# Firefox displays mp4 video with wrong aspect ratio

Tags: html, firefox, video, html5-video, aspect-ratio

I have a simple HTML5 Page ([LINK](http://koraysavci.com/testvideo.html)) with a video element. Its source refers to a mp4 video:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>test video page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video src="testvideo.mp4" controls></video>
    </body>
</html>
```

Firefox (44.0.2) displays the video with a different (wrong) aspect ratio than Chrome or IE.

If I log the videoWidth property of the video element on the developer conosle it's 360 for FF and 512 for other browsers.

Is there a special reason for that?

Is it possible to force FF to get the correct aspect ratio?

Comment: It's 512 in Firefox Developer Edition (46), maybe there was a bug that they've fixed recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed with the recent update.